# PHP preg pattern needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
0 10 2 012 11 12 12 test -f 13 x   xx
0 2   102 012 12 12 test -f 11 xxddd 22x
0 102 01 2  1    12   12 test -f 12 xxx
```

I need to find the number (between 1 and 5 digits) following the `-f` parameter using `preg_match()`.

I'm a total bumpkin regarding PCRE matches.

I played arround with online preg testers and get stuck with `\(.*)-f(\d{1,5})(.*)$\`

Answer (score 1):

Oh I didnt notice how close I got it:

```
\^.* -f (\d{1,4}).*$\

Array
(
    [0] =>     0 10 2 012 11 12 12 test -f 13 x   xx
    [1] => 13
)
```

Comment: actually you only need `-f\s+(\d+)\s`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm going to accept any working pattern posted by anyone if you feel free to answer yours...

Comment: I agree he doesn't need `^.*`, but your `\d+` will provide 1 or more digits, a number which could exceed 5 (he wants only digits up to 5).

Comment: usually when you parse a parameter you want the complete value until the next whitespace. reducing this to 5 just because you only have values with that length at the moment seems short sighted.

Comment: I agree, but I got the impression a string of numbers might follow the -f and he only wanted the first 5. Maybe I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: You are both right in your own way. The number can also be 7 digits long, I just expect it to never exceed my limit. After that argument there is either a whitespace or end of string. After the digit I want to grep, there is either `whitespace + any character` or nothing